# Writing new line in file with unique parameter

Tags: python, list, file

```
namestaj = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r")
oldNamestaj = namestaj.read()
namestaj.close()

kategorija = open("kategorija_namestaja.txt", "r")
oldKategorija = kategorija.read()
kategorija.close()

sifra = input("\nUneti šifru entiteta >> ")
naziv = input("Uneti naziv entiteta >> ")
boja = input("Uneti boju entiteta >> ")
kolicina = input("Uneti količinu entiteta u magacinu >> ")
cena = input("Uneti cenu entiteta >> ")
kategorija = input("Uneti kategoriju entiteta >> ")
opis = input("Uneti opis entiteta >> ")

namestaj = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "w")
namestaj.write(oldNamestaj)
dataNamestaj = "\n" + sifra + "|" + naziv + "|" + boja + "|" + kolicina + "|" + cena + "|" + kategorija
namestaj.write(dataNamestaj)
namestaj.close()

kategorija_fajl = open("kategorija_namestaja.txt", "w")
kategorija_fajl.write(oldKategorija)
dataKategorija = "\n" + kategorija + "|" + opis
kategorija_fajl.write(dataKategorija)
kategorija_fajl.close()
```

I need to write new line in file and must include unique parameters.
sifra and kategorija are unique parameter so if exist some parameter with that name program will pop up warning (sifra is INT, kategorija is STR).
Also what is best way to improve current code ?

Comment: please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i think code is very readable. need just to include unique parameters without breaking , i tried but program colapsed many times.
input's are on my language, just ignore what is in parenthesis

Comment: I didn't get what is your problem exactly! can you provide more detail about the problem you have?

Comment: Okey, so sifra and kategorija are unique parameters so it must be unchangeable.
When is my input same as sifra's parametar in file must pop up warning, same for kategorija.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the file to know it's contents and prevent duplicated fields, so this code could be rewritten,

```
namestaj = open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r")
oldNamestaj = namestaj.read()
namestaj.close()
```

To,

```
sifra_in_file = set()
kategorija_in_file = set()
with open("komad_namestaja.txt", "r") as namestaj:
    for line in namestaj:
        line = line.trim()  # Remove trailing '\n'
        sifra, naziv, boja, kolicina, cena, kategorija = line.split('|')  # Assume no field has '|'
        sifra_in_file.add(sifra)
        kategorija_in_file.add(kategorija)
```

Later, you can check if `sifra` or `kategorija` are in the data you read from the file with:

```
if kategorija in kategorija_in_file:
    # Print a warning
```